# grid_canopy failed to create vrt with catalog

Tags: lidr

I use this command but it failed to create the vrt file :

```
chm <- grid_canopy(ctg, 1, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15), c(0,1), subcircle = 0.2))
```

it is possible to add attribute to non create the vrt file to the command grid_canopy ?

the error message :

I know that the question is very short, but i can't send to you the entire las files. This is the error message :

```
Error in system(cmd, intern = TRUE) : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\bin\GDALBU~1.EXE -vrtnodata "-Inf" "C:/Users/po76844/Documents/lidar/la_fresse_la_joux/normalized/grid_metrics.vrt" "C:/Users/po76844/Documents/lidar/la_fresse_la_joux/normalized/14585_Joux-Fresse_14585_Joux-Fresse_Semis_classeL93-IGN69_000001_L93_IGN69_normalized_normalized.tif" "C:/Users/po76844/Documents/lidar/la_fresse_la_joux/normalized/14585_Joux-Fresse_14585_Joux-Fresse_Semis_classeL93-IGN69_000002_L93_IGN69_normalized_normalized.tif"
```

Comment: Use `options(lidR.buildVRT = FALSE)`. But you should include something more informative in your question. *It failed* does not help to fix.

Comment: I know that the question is very short, but i can't send to you the entire las files. This is the error message :

Comment: I guess it is the windows bug I fixed. I may have been fixed in the next version coming soon.

Comment: @JRR, thanks a lot for this reactivity !

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I have the same error but usin `grid_metrics`, it did not created the vrt file when applied to a catalog